# Local vars javascript module pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

How can I refer to a local variable inside a private function? For example, in the next code, in function myDisplay how can I get the object myObject of show function object and obtain id = 'B'?

```
var charge = (function($){

    var open = function(){
        var myObj = {
            id: 'A'
        };
    };

    var show = function(){
        var myObj = {
            id: 'B'
        };
        myDisplay();
    };

    function myDisplay(){
        //Here, how to refer to var myObj of show function object?
    }       
    return {
        open: open,
        show: show
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You cannot (fortunately). Pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea behind [scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) is that you can't. `myObj` is private to the function stored in `show`.

Furthermore, in this particular example, `myObj` won't even exist unless a call to `show()` is actually in progress. Consider this point. It won't even exist during the `myDisplay()` call. (And two different calls to `show()` will each have different `myObj` instances.)

If you want the outer function and show to share data, move `myObj` out to the outer scope - the same scope that `ret` is in.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var charge = (function($) {
        var myObjA = {
            id: 'A'
        };

    var myObjB = {
                id: 'B'
            }

        var open = function() {

        };

        var show = function() {

            myDisplay();
        };

        function myDisplay() {
            console.log(myObj);
            //Here, how to refer to var myObj of show function object?
        };

        return {
            open: open,
            show: show
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

I recommended you use module pattern like that.
And, because the javascripts closure. 
You can't read the myObj as you want it.
I provided you a solution hope you like it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I want to access id = 'B'  then it must be ouside the show function too, right?

Comment: Yes! you're right. And I post it for you into the new answer

Comment: But, uhm, now you have two vars local to the outer `charge` function, both called `myObj`. In `myDisplay()`, what is `myObj.id`? `A` or `B`?